# Benchmarking whole method much slower than cumulative total of each line individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, benchmarking

I have a method which takes about 500ms when using `Benchmark.realtime {method_name}`, but when I do the same Benchmark for each line that makes up the method, the cumulative total is ≈16ms. How can this be?

The method:

```
def spotlight_listings
  spotlights = Listing.spotlights.on_sale (0.0003s)
  return if spotlights.empty? (0.011s)

  all_genre_ids = spotlights.map(&:genre_ids).flatten (0.00015s)
  @genre_ids = all_genre_ids.sort_by { |el| all_genre_ids.count(el) }.reverse.uniq.first(4) (0.000026s)
  hash = {} (0.0000018s)
  @genre_ids.each do |g| (0.004s - for the block)
    hash.store(g, spotlights.filter { |s| s.genre_ids.include?(g) }.first(4))
  end
  @spotlight_listings = hash (0.0000017s)
end
```

Comment: How are you testing the whole method? Does that involve instantiating an object or something else resource intensive that doesn't need to happen when testing each line on its own?

Comment: These figures are not reliable and it doesn't make much sense to reflect on them. Many non-deterministic things happen under the hood in parallel with your code execution (like context switching by OS), and they might affect a single run benchmark dramatically. To minimize the "other things" impact on the benchmarks the code in question must be executed many times (dozens of thousands).

Comment: Turns out `Listing.spotlights.on_sale` is lazy loaded when run as a line by itself, but when triggered into memory takes roughly 350ms.

Comment: It's normal for time costs not to add linearly on a modern CPU with caches, out-of-order exec, and branch-prediction.  Doing one simple thing repeatedly can be very fast; doing it between other steps on different data might not be.  Especially if it means you touch different memory and get more cache misses in your real code.  Or yeah, language optimizations like lazy eval can defeat simplistic benchmarks that don't use results, like here or in ahead-of-time compiled languages.